# How to tell if a file or directory can be renamed in OSX?

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

I am writing a small Mac app which has a functionality to rename files or directories. I want to determine if a file or directory can be renamed, if it's not renamable, I will not allow users to rename it, such as some system directories: the "Downloads", "Documents" or "Desktop" directory in the home directory. The problem is how can I determine it?

Comment: I have tried to read the API of NSFileManager, but there isn't a method to tell whether a file can be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

All the directories you list can be renamed. There is big difference between "cannot be renamed" and "in most cases should not be renamed."

If you want the list of well-known directories (which in most cases shouldn't be renamed), they are listed in the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2). The specific ones in the user's home directory are:

- Applications—Contains user-specific apps.
- Desktop—Contains the items on the user’s desktop.
- Documents—Contains user documents and files.
- Downloads—Contains files downloaded from the Internet.
- Library—Contains user-specific app files (hidden in OS X v10.7 and later).
- Movies—Contains the user’s video files.
- Music—Contains the user’s music files.
- Pictures—Contains the user’s photos.
- Public—Contains content the user wants to share.
- Sites—Contains web pages used by the user’s personal site. (Web Sharing must be enabled to display these pages.)

In recent versions of OS X, there are system-level directories that actually cannot be renamed (due to System Integrity Protection). You can detect these by checking the extended attributes for `com.apple.rootless`, for example with `xattr`:

```
$ xattr /System/
com.apple.rootless
```

See `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` for reading these attributes with `NSFileManager`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I am home.